# DC Output current control

Tags: current, dc, control, constant-current

Can I use a 14v 2A dc adapter on 12v 1A  dc rated device?

Now what i did is by a buck controller i set the voltage to 12v but there is no variables to control the current in that buck control module. So i don't know how to control 2A current to 1A,because the device that i want to connect is rated as 12V 1A (As it's input).I'm afraid about that the current cause any damage to the device

Comment: Thought experiment: what controls the current fed into a 55 W (4.5 A) car headlight and a 6 W (0.5 A) tail light when they're both on the same 12 V supply?

Comment: Mebin, It's hard to say. When you increase the voltage across a "rated device" from its 12 V to 14 V, there will be some impact. But we don't know what kind of impact without knowing all the intimate details of the "rated device." With incandescent bulbs, for example, their impedance increases with increasing temperature. So those would likely be safer. But LEDs are quite a different thing altogether. So a lot depends on the "rated device." You will need to open your hand and let us see what you are holding inside it. What exactly is this "rated device?"

Comment: @jonk You missed that OP uses a buck converter to bring voltage back to 12V, so this question will get closed as it is a duplicate of the age old question about different amperage supplies being compatible.

Comment: @Justme Thanks. Got it.

Comment: Mebin Antony - The device's power input specification you gave of a fixed 12 V indicates that your device (whatever it is) requires a constant *voltage* input, so your question is a duplicate of this one: "[Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/34745)". That explains why you don't need to be concerned about the higher current *capability* of the replacement supply. A suitable voltage regulator (e.g. buck converter) would be required, as you described, to convert the 14 V supply to the 12 V required by your device.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use a 14v 2A dc adapter on 12v 1A dc rated device?

Not directly. But with a buck converter to step down the voltage to 12V, yes.

> I don't know how to control 2A current to 1A,because the device that i want to connect is rated as 12V 1A (As it's input).I'm afraid about that the current cause any damage to the device.

This is actually a very common confusion, so let me clarify a few things.

If a wall adaptor is rated (say) 15V 3A, it means the wall adaptor will output a voltage of 15V and its maximum output current is 3A. The 15V 3A rating doesn't mean that the wall adaptor will always push 3A through a load at all times at 15V, as that is impossible.

If a load is rated at (say) 12V 1A, it means that the load needs a voltage of 12V (with a small error tolerance) and that it will draw not more than 1A from the source. Even if you connect a 12V 10A power source to the load, the load will be perfectly fine and will draw a current less than or equal to 1A from the source.

So you can safely power a 12V 1A rated device by a 12V power source that can output **atleast** 1A.